# Convert any number to one digit number

Tags: java

Consider the number 2345.If you multiply the digits of it then you get the number 120.Now if you again multiply the digits of 120 then you will get 0 which is one digit.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SmallestNum 
{
    int prod=1,sum=0;
    void product(int m)
    {         
        while(m!=0)
        {
           int a=m%10;
           m=m/10;
           prod=prod*a;
        }   
       System.out.println(prod);            
    }


   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
       int x=scn.nextInt();
       SmallestNum sn=new SmallestNum();
       sn.product(x);
   }
}
```

I can get the 120 from this code.But how can i do the same procedure with 120 and get the answer 0.Pls help me.

Comment: Use recursion of the same function untill numbet.toString().lenght()==1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int reduceToOneDigit(int inputNumber){
    int result = 1;
    while(inputNumber > 0){
        result *= (inputNumber % 10);
        inputNumber /= 10;
    }
    if (result > 9)
        result = reduceToOneDigit(result);
    return result;
}
```

So basically: multiply the digits of your inputNumber. If the result has more than one digit (so result is > 9, at least 10) call method recursively on the result.

Alternatively, do the same without recursion, using a do-while loop:

```
public int reduceToOneDigitNoRecursion(int inputNumber){
    int result = 1;
    do{
          while(inputNumber > 0){
              result *= (inputNumber % 10);
              inputNumber /= 10;
          }
    }
    while(result > 9);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add an other loop around your while, the end condition being `prod < 10`, i.e. having only one number.

```
void product(int m)
{
    int prod;
    do {
        prod = 1;
        while(m!=0)
        {
           int a = m%10;
           m = m / 10;
           prod *= a;
        }   
        System.out.println(prod);
     } while (prod >= 10);
}
```

Comment: If you initialize prod inside the do-while loop, then every iteration will reset its value to 1. I believe you should initialize prod before getting inside any loops here.

Answer (score 0):

Use recurssion

```
void product(int m)
{

        if(m%10 == 0){
        return;
        }

        while(m!=0)
        {
           int a=m%10;
           m=m/10;
           prod=prod*a;
        }

           System.out.println(prod);
           product(prod);//repeat the procedure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive call the function

```
  if(String.valueOf(prod).length()>1){
       product(prod)
    }
```

complete code

```
public class SmallestNum 
{
int prod=1,sum=0;
void product(int m)
{

        while(m!=0)
        {
           int a=m%10;
           m=m/10;
           prod=prod*a;
        }
        if(String.valueOf(prod).length()>1){
           product(prod)
        }
           System.out.println(prod);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
   Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
   int x=scn.nextInt();
   SmallestNum sn=new SmallestNum();
   sn.product(x);
}
}
```

Comment: this code is not working.I want this type of output. 2467=2*4*6*7=336  336=3*3*6=54  54=5*4=20  20=2*0=0

Answer (score 0):

make member function product return to an int. then instead of sn.product(x);

```
int p = sn.product(x);
while (p > 9)
{ 
    p = sn.product(t);
}
```